# button invisible with condition from field

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

This is my py

```
purchase_type = fields.Selection([
    ('import', 'Import'),
    ('local', 'Local'),
], string='Purchase Type')
```

This is my xml

```
<button name="action_approve" string="Approve" type="object" states="confirm" groups="ts_addons_tbk.group_tbk_director,ts_addons_tbk.group_tbk_exim,ts_addons_tbk.group_tbk_manager"  />
```

I want to make the button visible only when the purchase_type is import andthe groups are ts_addons_tbk.group_tbk_director and ts_addons_tbk.group_tbk_exim.
Thank you sir.

Comment: On which model is field `purchase_type` defined? On which model is the view defined, where the button definition was made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `attrs`:

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('purchase_type', '!=', 'import')]}">
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/fr/developer/reference/addons/views.html#semantic-components) (check the [list view buttons](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/fr/developer/reference/addons/views.html#reference-views-list-button) link):

> `states is shorthand for invisible attrs` and should be a list of states, comma separated, requires that the model has a state field and that it is used in the view.

And Odoo warns about using `states` in combination with `attrs`:

> Using states in combination with attrs may lead to unexpected results as domains are combined with a logical AND.

***Edit***:

You can remove `states` and use only `attrs` (OR operator):

```
attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('purchase_type', '!=', 'import'), ('state', '!=', 'confirm')]}"
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have tried it but the button still there even when the purchase_type is local.

Comment: This happens because you use `attrs` in combination with `states`. The button will be invisible when the purchase type is not `import` and the state is not `confirm`, note that the `AND` operator is used when you combine states and attrs.  Check my edit

Comment: But how about the groups? I only want to show the button for ts_addons_tbk.group_tbk_director and ts_addons_tbk.group_tbk_exim BUT not for ts_addons_tbk.group_tbk_manager.